# Java to php, Byte, Type, Array

Tags: java, php

Here is a small Java Code Snippet.

```
ConfigData[] cd = new ConfigData[1];
cd[0] = new ConfigData();
byte[] tmpbyte ={1,(byte)0x01};
cd[0].settmpdata(tmpbyte);
```

"ConfigData" is my custom Type (int, Byte Array).

In my last thread i found the tip how to Build / work with a "ByteArray" in php.
But this seems to be a question of the structure of those objects / array.

So..
How can i depict that in PHP.

Comment: So, what's your question exactly...? What is it that you're trying to "map" from Java to PHP?

Comment: As @Less says, it's not easy to discern exactly what you're asking here. But in general, I would say that PHP and Java are different languages; it's not always possible or advisable to do things in exactly the same way in different languages -- they each have their own way of doing things. In particular, PHP's data type handling is significantly different to Java's. My advice is not to try to force PHP into doing things Java's way; you'll end up with awkward constructs that could have been done a lot more simply. The same applies in the other direction, of course, and between other languages.

Comment: @ChristianNRW, PHP doesn't have types, when dealing with a variable, you must know what it is

Comment: @ChristianNRW is this a web application? Wouldn't it be a lot more feasible to send your data through a standardized format, like using WebService? (You didn't specify any details of why or how often you are trying to communicate between Java and PHP...)

Comment: @ppeterka The thread above describes the Data for a webservice. The Java Snippet is, how to set the data in Java. I need the depic of that in php

Comment: @ChristianNRW and why do you use byte arrays? What kind of data do you want to send? Why don't you use 'more convenient' data types, like integers and strings?

Comment: @ppeterka It is a Config for a small Hardware and they love Byte Arrays :-) The webservice Type is described as: `<complexType name="ConfigData"><sequence><element name="tmpdata" nillable="true" type="xsd:base64Binary"/><element name="integerdata" type="xsd:int"/></sequence></complexType>`  and with my request: `<param1 xsi:type="tns1:ConfigData"><tmpdata xsi:type="xsd:base64Binary"/><integerdata xsi:type="int">5</iPortId></param1>` i only receive Errors like this: **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that this can make some guidelines for you, in the terms of what you can do in PHP, and in a relation to your code snippet (the code is tested):

```
<?php

// define class
class ConfigData
{
    var $intVal;
    var $tmpData;
}

$cData = new ConfigData();             // new ConfigData instance
$array[0] = $cData;                 // put it in a single element array
$array[0]->intVal = 5;                 // assign an integer to intVal
$array[0]->tmpData = array(1, 1, 2);  // assign an array of whatever to tmpData

foreach($array[0]->tmpData as $val)   // iterate through assigned array
    echo $val." ";                     // print array item (and append " " )

?>
```

Now, you might also want to check how byte manipulation in PHP is achieved. I suggest you to do a little Google search, and maybe check the official manual. You question was not specific enough, so I can't say more.